# Can all of L2/L3 cache be used by data? If so, why does the Graviton 3 bandwidth plot drop off after half the L2/L3 size, but only gradually?

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, arm64, cpu-cache, memory-bandwidth

Consider Graviton3, for example. It's a 64-core CPU with per-core caches 64KiB L1d and 1MiB L2.  And a shared L3 of 64MiB across all cores. The RAM bandwidth per socket is 307GB/s ([source](https://www.nextplatform.com/2022/01/04/inside-amazons-graviton3-arm-server-processor/)).

In this plot ([source](https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/05/29/graviton-3-first-impressions/)),

[image]

we see that all-cores bandwidth drops off to roughly half, when the data exceeds 4MB.  This makes sense: 64x 64KiB = 4 MiB is the size of the L1 data cache.

But why does the next cliff begin at 32MB? And why is the drop-off so gradual there?  The private L2 caches of 64 cores is a total of 64 MiB, same as the shared L3 size.

Comment: *8MB L1* - What?  L1d is 64KiB per core, per-core private.  8MB total is a really weird way to talk about it without even mentioning that it (and L2) are per-core private, unlike L3 which is shared.  Especially since that 8MiB includes L1i cache!  Only for this very special case of having each thread only touch part of the total working set, evenly distributed, does it make any sense to talk about total sizes of per-core vs. shared caches the same way.

Comment: @PeterCordes As far as I can tell all of L1,L2,L3 caches are split among the 64 cores. But if you can make any improvements to the question, please feel free to edit.

Comment: @PeterCordes The table says "L3 cache/core". This seems to imply that it's not shared, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: No sane CPU would have per-core private L3 caches without any shared cache.  It may be distributed around the chip, with a slice of it near every core.  (That's how Intel does it).  Or it may just be a useful number to save you the trouble of doing the math.  It might not be a single unified L3, though; for example AMD CPUs have a separate L3 for each CCX (core complex of 4 or 8 cores). (Which is amazing if each core is working on a separate chunk of the array, without any inter-core communication or data sharing).  That table is not telling us how it's actually divided up / shared.

Comment: From your https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/05/29/graviton-3-first-impressions/ link: *Ice Lake and Graviton 3 take roughly parallel caching strategies. Both implement a chip-wide unified L3. And both give their cores large private L2 caches to insulate them from L3 latency. AMD takes a different approach, giving up a chip-wide cache in favor of giving each core cluster a very fast L3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks from the plot like they may not have tested any sizes between 32M and 64M. Looks like a straight line between those points on all 3 CPUs.

Since 64M is the total size of both L2 and L3, I'd expect a test like this to have slowed most of the way down at 64M. As Brendan says, page tables and a bit of code will take space, competing with the actual intended test data.  If the benchmark loop is tight, stack won't come into play, except for interrupt handling.

Once you're evicting anything from a working set slightly larger than cache, you often evict almost everything before getting back to it, depending on pseudo-LRU luck.  I'd expect a test size or 48 or even 56 MiB to be a lot closer to the 32 MiB data point than the 64 MiB data point.

Comment: So you think the cliff should begin at around 64MB, but what we are seeing is a plotting artifact?

Comment: @MWB: No, begin around 60 to 63 MB, and already have fallen off significantly by 64M like the data we have shows.  But yes, the fact that it looks like it starts at 32 is probably a benchmark sampling / step size artifact.

Comment: Is it possible that L1 is using the LRU removal heuristic, while L2/L3 are using something else, like random? I think this might explain why one cliff is sharp, while the other is not.

Comment: @MWB: It's quite unlikely that L1d uses full LRU, that takes quite a few bits to track.  Almost always caches use pseudo-LRU.  (Which is semi-random).  But with both L2 and L3 being the same total size (64M) that could be a factor.  And also having some low-frequency demand (e.g. from interrupts) can trigger some occasional replacements.  Some CPUs use an adaptive replacement policy in L3 (e.g. Intel since IvB: https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/) which can give *some* hits when the working set is larger, although it's intended for a mix of hot vs. non-temporal data.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, on a running Graviton 3 in AWS, an lscpu gives me 32MiB for L3 and not 64 MiB.

Caches (sum of all):
L1d:                 4 MiB (64 instances)
L1i:                 4 MiB (64 instances)
L2:                  64 MiB (64 instances)
L3:                  32 MiB (1 instance)

The original question is assuming an L3 of 64 MiB across all cores.

> Blockquote
> But why does the next cliff begin at 32MB? And why is the drop-off so gradual there? The private L2 caches of 64 cores is a total of 64 MiB, same as the shared L3 size.
> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

> Can all of L2/L3 cache be used by data?

In theory, yes; but only if there's no "non-data" (code) in the cache, only if you count "all data" (and don't just count a process' data and ignore things like stack and page tables), and only if there isn't any aliasing problems.

> But why does the next cliff begin at 32MB? And why is the drop-off so gradual there?

For a fully associative cache I'd expect a sudden drop off at/near 32 MiB. However, large caches are almost never fully associative as it costs way to much to find anything in the cache.

As associativity decreases the chance of conflicts increases. For example, for an 8-way associative 64 MiB cache the pathological case is that everything conflicts and you're only able to effectively use 8 MiB of it.

More specifically, for a 64 MiB cache (with unknown associativity), and an "assumed Linux" environment that lacks support for [cache coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coloring), it's reasonable to expect a smooth drop off that ends at 64 MiB.

Comment: It's not clear from the graph whether they tested any sizes between 32M and 64M.  Looks like a straight line between those points on all 3 CPUs.  Since 64M is the total size of both L2 and L3, I'd expect a test like this to have slowed most of the way down at 64M.  (As you say, page tables and a bit of code will take space; if the benchmark loop is tight, stack won't come into play, except for interrupt handling.)  Once you're evicting anything from a working set slightly too large, you often evict almost everything before getting back to it, depending on pseudo-LRU luck.

Comment: *"For a fully associative cache I'd expect a sudden drop off at/near 32 MiB."* -- Half of L2? Why?

Comment: @MWB: Because I kept using "32 MiB" everywhere when I should've been using "64 MiB" everywhere.  :-)